# datatstax opscenter v 4.1.2 short-os collection failed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, storage, metrics, opscenter

I've installed Datastax opscenter `v4.1.2`.  It was bundled with Datastax Cassandra Community edition version `2.0.8`.  I'm running these on Windows Server `2008 R2 64-bit`.  When I open opscenter all agents are connected and all the stats are displayed **except** the widget for Storage capacity which shows no information.

---

The opescenterd.log files shows (IP address removed):

```
 2014-06-16 12:24:01+0100 [local] ERROR: Agent for xx.xxx.x.xx was unable to complete operation (http://xx.xxx.x.xx:61621/os-metric/disk-space?): java.io.IOException: Process failed: wmic LogicalDisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceId,Size,FreeSpace /Format:csv

  Exit val: 44210
  Output:
Invalid XSL format (or) file name.
```

---

The opscenter-agent log shows:

```
 ERROR [os-metrics-11] 2014-06-16 12:29:39,564 Short os-stats collector failed: Process failed: wmic LogicalDisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceId,Size,FreeSpace /Format:csv

Exit val: 44210

Output:

Invalid XSL format (or) file name.
```

---

Both messages are repeated at regular intervals.  Can anyone advise on this error please?

Comment: I've never seen the "Invalid XSL format" error before.  Googling seems to suggest it's related to locale.  Are you running on a non en-US version of windows?  Try running the following command from cmd.exe and paste the output here:  wmic LogicalDisk where DriveType=3 get DeviceId,Size,FreeSpace /Format:csv

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It was indeed the locale which is not set here to en-US.  Running the wmic command pointed to the /Format:csv causing the problem in that csv.xsl couldn't be found hence the "Invalid XSL format" (which acutally mean't file not found).  As a workaround I copied en-US/csv.xsl the the system32 directory and all the metrics now work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/a9beeed3-99f0-4627-ba1e-aa0161fa58c9#be9e599a-5cd8-4238-9918-df650a98c66b) in Windows 7 WMIC. When you use Dutch regional settings in an English Windows installation, WMIC searches for the xsl files inside `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\nl-NL`, instead of `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\en-US` where they are.

Workarounds:

1. Create a folder named `C:\Windows\system32\wbem\nl-NL` (or whichever locale you use, check `HKCU\Control Panel\International\LocaleName`) and copy the `C:\Windows\system32\wbem\en-US\*.xsl` files into it.
2. Change your regional settings to match your Windows language version, log out and back in.
3. Specify the full path: `WMIC process get /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-US\csv"`.